# determining matlab parallel pool size in a batch job on a cluster

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I want to verify that my cluster is configured correctly, and I thought issuing the command below will run the following script and output the poolsize into a text file as well as where my screen output is directed (by the batch management environment). Instead I only see output at the end, with nothing in the error file either. How shall I get this done?

Command:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop < test.m
```

Script:

```
clear;
delete(gcp);
parpool;
poolsize = poolobj.NumWorkers
save poolsize.txt poolsize -ascii
exit();
poolobj = gcp('nocreate'); % If no pool, do not create new one.
if isempty(poolobj)
    poolsize = 0;
else
    poolsize = poolobj.NumWorkers
end
save poolsizefile poolsize;
poolsize
exit();
```

(The second half never worked, so I even stopped trying, thus the first exit.)

Output:

```
>> >> Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... Warning: Found 1 pre-existing communicating job(s) created by pool that are
running, and 3 communicating job(s) that are pending or queued. You can use
'delete(myCluster.Jobs)' to remove all jobs created with profile local. To
create 'myCluster' use 'myCluster = parcluster('local')'.
```

Comment: Why are you calling `exit`? This will close matlab and makes everything below unreachable.

Comment: I am issuing this into a batch, so the job should close. Interestingly, it never does, it always times out, maybe it's worth mentioning in the main text. (The environment in inaccessible in any case.)

Comment: If you kill your workers using `exit`, it's no wonder you receive a timeout. This is not a proper way to terminate a job!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest using the `-r` option to MATLAB to run your script as there are some occasional weirdnesses when piping input as you're doing, e.g.

```
matlab -nodisplay -r test
```

Then, I would change line 2 to state

```
delete(gcp('nocreate'))
```

to ensure you don't create a pool simply to delete it. Then, the next bit should be

```
poolobj = parpool;
poolsize = poolobj.NumWorkers;
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess you also tested this?

Comment: Thanks. I got this note : Error using parpool (line 86)
Found an interactive session. You cannot have multiple interactive sessions
open simultaneously. To terminate the existing session, use 'delete(gcp)'.

Error in BayesBootstrapMaster (line 5)
poolobj = parpool;

Comment: Ok, but that means you must have already opened a pool. `delete(gcp('nocreate'))` is guaranteed to ensure no pool is open, without creating one. If you do simply `delete(gcp)`, then that might open a pool and then delete it (depending on your parallel preferences).

Comment: Thanks, only the latter works. But I had no open pool, just fired up a fresh insurance of Matlab. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the latter works"? Are you saying that `delete(gcp('nocreate'))" doesn't work? I don't know of any way that that can fail... (providing it completes without error of course).

Comment: Yes, `delete(gcp)` produced no error message about an interactive session, `delete(gcp('nocreate'))` did, I don't know why. Thanks again!